# How to specify number of reviewers based on origin branch in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-repos

I'm currently trying to set the following policies for pull requests in Azure DevOps but don't know if it's even possible.

- `feature/*` -> development (requires 2 approvals)
- `incident/*` -> development (requires 1 approval)
- `bugfix/*` -> development (requires 1 approval)

Basically, I want to set the number of approvals required based on the origin branch. I know it's possible to specify the number of reviewers needed for a branch globally (e.g., all PRs to development require 2 approvals). It's also possible to specify reviewers based on files changed.

But is it possible to set policies like this as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK - no, there is no settings that would support this. It is possible to create branch policies on folder and wildcard, for example feature/* policies, and then all branches under that folder inherit the same policies.

But for your requirement i would recommend to think about automated creation of a PR. For example, you could create 2 builds (one for feature/* that creates a PR with 2 reviewers, and one for incident/* and bugfix/* that creates a PR with 1 reviewer). For a fast google search i have found following Task, that would create an automated PR: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ShaykiAbramczyk.CreatePullRequest